# Operate along a dimension without writing back data in dask array on Xarray

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, dask, python-xarray

I have a dataset with 3 dimensions ('time', 'x' and 'y'). I want to apply this function `foo` along the time dimension:

```
def foo(arr):
    lo, hi = np.percentile(arr, (1,99))
    arr = np.clip(arr, lo, hi)
    arr = (arr - lo) / (hi - lo)
    return arr
```

Basically, I want to scale each "image" in the time dimension with a function like `foo`

In numpy, I could just do something like:

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
   data[i] = foo(data[i])
```

but since the data is stored in dask arrays, I am unable to write back the modified data. I hit this error:

```
TypeError: this variable's data is stored in a dask array, which does not support item assignment. To assign to this variable, you must first load it into memory explicitly using the .load() method or accessing its .values attribute.
```

How would one go about doing this in xarray/dask?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop over the time dimension, you can do this in a vectorized way:

```py
da = xr.tutorial.open_dataset(
    "air_temperature", chunks={"lat": -1, "lon": -1, "time": 10}
)["air"]


def scale_image(da, quantiles):
    quantiles = da.quantile(quantiles, dim=("lat", "lon"))
    lower = quantiles.isel(quantile=0, drop=True)
    upper = quantiles.isel(quantile=1, drop=True)
    clipped = xr.apply_ufunc(np.clip, da, lower, upper, dask="allowed")
    return (clipped - lower) / (upper - lower)


scaled = scale_image(da, quantiles=[0.01, 0.99])
```

Like this it is not necessary to load the whole array into memory.

I realized that you can use xarray's `apply_ufunc` directly with your `foo` function as well, if you provide the `axis` argument to `np.percentile` and take care of making the array shapes consistent.
It seems, that the dask-version of the `percentile` function is not implemented for multi-dimensional arrays, but you can use the `parallelized` option for `apply_ufunc` to make it work with the numpy function:

```
def foo(arr):
    lo, hi = np.percentile(arr, (1, 99), axis=[1, 2])
    arr = np.clip(arr, lo[:, None, None], hi[:, None, None])
    return (arr - lo[:, None, None]) / (hi[:, None, None] - lo[:, None, None])

scaled2 = xr.apply_ufunc(foo, da, dask="parallelized")
```